# SMILE link error with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, smile

I am working with an older version of a C++ SMILE library for Bayesian analysis that was freely available before they started selling it. I have no idea what compiler was used to create the libraries, but all I have are the headers and lib files. I am attempting to wrap these libraries with managed C++ code for use in our newer .Net applications build with Visual Studio 2010 SP1. Because I have to use the /MT switch, I have to create a DLL to export the class creation and functions to the CLR DLL project that wraps them into a new class.

The source for the first unmanaged DLL is like this, and has no issues compiling/linking into the DLL:

CPP_Network.h

```
#include "smile.h"

#pragma once

#ifndef DllExport
#define DllExport    __declspec( dllexport )
#endif

#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C"
{
#endif

DllExport DSL_network* DSL_network_Create();
DllExport void DSL_network_Release(DSL_network* instance);

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

CPP_Network.cpp

```
#include "CPP_Network.h"

DSL_network* DSL_network_Create()
{
    return new DSL_network();
}

void DSL_network_Release(DSL_network* instance)
{
    if (instance != NULL)
        delete instance;
}
```

The managed wrapper source is like this, but generates linker errors below:

CLR_Network.h

```
#pragma once

#define SMILE_VC_NO_AUTOLINK
#define SMILEXML_VC_NO_AUTOLINK
#define SMILEARN_VC_NO_AUTOLINK

#include "CPP_Network.h"

using namespace System;

namespace smile {
    public ref class Network
    {
    private:
        DSL_network *instance;
    public:
        Network();
        ~Network();
    };
}
```

CLR_Network.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "CLR_Network.h"

smile::Network::Network()
{
    instance = DSL_network_Create();
}

smile::Network::~Network()
{
    DSL_network_Release(instance);
    instance = 0;
}
```

I get the following link errors when linking to the unmanaged DLL:

```
error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0004C3) "public: __thiscall DSL_doubleArray::DSL_doubleArray(class DSL_doubleArray const &)" (??0DSL_doubleArray@@$$FQAE@ABV0@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall DSL_Dmatrix::DSL_Dmatrix(class DSL_Dmatrix const &)" (??0DSL_Dmatrix@@$$FQAE@ABV0@@Z)
error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0004C4) "public: void __thiscall DSL_doubleArray::CleanUp(void)" (?CleanUp@DSL_doubleArray@@$$FQAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall DSL_doubleArray::~DSL_doubleArray(void)" (??1DSL_doubleArray@@$$FQAE@XZ)
error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0004C6) "public: int __thiscall DSL_intArray::SetSize(int)" (?SetSize@DSL_intArray@@$$FQAEHH@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall DSL_intArray::DSL_intArray(class DSL_intArray const &)" (??0DSL_intArray@@$$FQAE@ABV0@@Z)
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall DSL_doubleArray::CleanUp(void)" (?CleanUp@DSL_doubleArray@@$$FQAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall DSL_doubleArray::~DSL_doubleArray(void)" (??1DSL_doubleArray@@$$FQAE@XZ)
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall DSL_intArray::SetSize(int)" (?SetSize@DSL_intArray@@$$FQAEHH@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall DSL_intArray::DSL_intArray(class DSL_intArray const &)" (??0DSL_intArray@@$$FQAE@ABV0@@Z)
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall DSL_doubleArray::DSL_doubleArray(class DSL_doubleArray const &)" (??0DSL_doubleArray@@$$FQAE@ABV0@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall DSL_Dmatrix::DSL_Dmatrix(class DSL_Dmatrix const &)" (??0DSL_Dmatrix@@$$FQAE@ABV0@@Z)
```

I ran dumpbin on smile.lib and saw the following link:

```
??0DSL_doubleArray@@QAE@ABV0@@Z
```

Running undname on that and the one the linker is looking for shows the same function declarations:

```
C:\>undname ??0DSL_doubleArray@@QAE@ABV0@@Z
Microsoft (R) C++ Name Undecorator
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Undecoration of :- "??0DSL_doubleArray@@QAE@ABV0@@Z"
is :- "public: __thiscall DSL_doubleArray::DSL_doubleArray(class DSL_doubleArray const &)"

C:\>undname ??0DSL_doubleArray@@$$FQAE@ABV0@@Z
Microsoft (R) C++ Name Undecorator
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Undecoration of :- "??0DSL_doubleArray@@$$FQAE@ABV0@@Z"
is :- "public: __thiscall DSL_doubleArray::DSL_doubleArray(class DSL_doubleArray const &)"
```

I'm guessing that the newer compiler is looking for a newer version of the link. Is there a way to make this work correcting the references somehow?

Comment: The mangling in the error has `$$F` (for example, `??0DSL_doubleArray@@$$FQAE@ABV0@@Z`), which means the function is considered _managed_. I haven't used clr enough, but you have a problem with how the library headers are included. Is there something like `extern "C"` for this?

Comment: @isanae I added `#pragma managed(push, off)` and `#pragma managed(pop)` around the `smile.h`, and it got rid of the unresolved tokens. I still have the unresolved external symbols for some reason. The only `extern "C"` is what I have in my example above. the SMILE library headers do not define any that I have found so far.